# Beginner Chess Question: Bringing out my queen early?

Tags: beginner, queens

Sometimes I bring my queen out early, however GMs say "Queen is vulnerable to attack and hinders development" I agree with that but most of the time I only bring it to f3 or around the 3rd-rank ex. b3/g3 threatening to take b7 pawn and forking rook and the knight.

Question:
Does it hinder my development if I try to bring it out to the 3rd row. I know it's vulnerable to Knight and Bishop attacks.

Comment: As user *kostas* said, never do that unless you see **obvious** benefit. You will only hinder your overall piece coordination, which will eventually squander your advantage as White.

Comment: The goal is the find the _best_ move in the position. Even if it's not immediately a problem to bring out the queen, it'll often be more useful to develop another piece that can actually safely do stuff early on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common wisdom is that bringing your Queen out early invites attack and eventually costs you time. And losing time is like giving your opponent free moves. So for players of a certain level, it is true that bringing out the Queen early is not helpful.

That being said, chess is a game between 2 people. It is not between "olde GM lore" and a person.

If you're having fun bring your Queen out early, or if you're winning games by doing it, then keep doing it. If you're playing tournaments, your rating will rise accordingly. By the last rounds you'll be playing the better players in your bracket.

At some point, your opponents will get stronger. You'll notice that an early Queen sortie is a detriment. At that point you'll need to up your game.

Consider not moving your Queen until you have at least 2 other piece off the back row. Getting those pieces 'out of the box' will go a long way towards giving you some good games.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my tactic to recapturing with Qxc4 to bring my queen to the 3rd rank; is that alright?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it hinders your development to bring your queen out to f3. Not only does the queen occupation of f3 take away the most natural square for your knight, but your queen is vulnerable to attack in the opening and middle game. Your castling is delayed. c2 is no longer defended, look out for your opponents Ng4. The whole shuffle of your queen at various third rank squares not only wastes time which you could use to develop other pieces, but the attack often only helps your opponent develop because when you attack a pawn, for example, your opponent may be able to develop a piece and defend the pawn at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Never ever do that unless the are tactics or exploiting opponent's inaccuracy in development. F3 is the natural square for your knight. If your opponent follows a normal development and you bring your Queen on the 3rd Rank for no particular reason(see above the only two reasons) that strategically losing. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

**Bringing out the queen early is bad only if it can be attacked**. Here're some examples:

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qe5+? 4. Be2 Nf6 5. Nf3 Qf5? 6. O-O
```

Black's position is a wreck because White has managed to develop with tempo two times (3. Nc3 and 5. Nf3), and is threatening to do it yet again (with an eventual d4-Bd3, gaining time yet again while opening the e-file for the f1-rook). These moves are "free" because while White is developing pieces, Black has to respond to the attack on the queen. This is why the standard move in this opening is 3...Qa5, which places the queen on a square which cannot be easily attacked.

However if the opponent cannot attack the queen, it's perfectly fine to bring out the queen early.

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 exd4 4. Nxd4 Nxd4? 5. Qxd4
```

In this line of the Scotch, okay, now White's queen is in the center, but Black can't attack it. If Black could still play ...Nc6, then yes, the queen is vulnerable, but the knight isn't there anymore. Black could play ...c5, but that permanently weakens the d5-square and after White moves the queen, Bc4 and Nc3 would turn Black's "gain of time" into seppuku.

Another, more sophisticated example:

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 e6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nc6 5. Nc3 Qc7
```

Once again Black has developed his queen early, but White has no good way to attack it. Playing Ndb5 or Ncb5 doesn't gain much time because the knights are already developed, and Black will regain the tempo eventually with ...a6. If White could play Bf4, then 5...Qc7 would be bad, but the line 6. Ndb5 Qb8 7. g3 (forcing Bf4) a6 8. Bf4? e5 would lose White a piece.

Conclusion: in the opening, feel free to develop your queen where it's active *as long as it cannot be easily attacked*. If the opponent pieces can leap into battle by attacking the queen, don't do it. If they can't, by all means.

Comment: I wouldn't play 4...Nxd4 in the Scotch but I'm not sure it deserves a full question mark. Other more mainstream Scotch lines where a Q comes out early are 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 exd4 4 Nxd4 Bc5 5.Be3 Qf6 and 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 exd4 4.Nxd4 Qh5. There are many Kings Gambit lines where Black gives an early queen check such as 1.e4 e5 2.f4 Qh5+.