# Analyze, improvement - My game without blunders?

Tags: analysis

When I first created this account I posted about how I am in a slump and kept blundering important games.

As of today, I think I have gotten out of that slump and I understand CHESS much better.

Here's my game, and I think I have no blunders here:

```
[Event "Unbalance Chess"]
[Site "windows"]
[Date "2015.09.20"]
[Round ""]
[White "Level 19"]
[Black "4444"]
[Result "0-1"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1"]

1... c5 2. Qf3 d6 3. Bb5+ Bd7 4. Bc4 Nf6 5. e5 d5 6. exf6 dxc4 7. Qxb7 Nc6 8.
Ne2 exf6 9. Nbc3 Rb8 10. Qa6 Qe7 11. O-O Nd4 12. Qxc4 Be6 13. Qd3 Rd8 14. f3 c4
15. Qe4 f5 16. Qe5 f6 17. Qa5 g6 18. Re1 Nc6 19. Qb5 Bd7 20. Nb1 Ne5 21. Qa5
Bh6 22. f4 Nc6 23. Qc3 g5 24. Qxc4 gxf4 25. a3 f3 26. gxf3 Ne5 27. Qb3 Be6 28.
Qc3 Rg8+ 29. Ng3 f4 30. Kh1 fxg3 31. hxg3 Rxg3 32. b3 Qg7 33. Re2 Rg1+ 34. Kh2
Bf4# 0-1
```

If there are any blunders please analyze and help me improve my practical play (tactics).

Comment: My first thought is that after 7 Qxb7??  Bc6 would trap the white queen - the queen has few squares to move to, trapping it just looks in the air.

Comment: We had a thread recently about why bringing out one's queen too early could be bad. This is a good example of why it can really go sideways.  By all rights, Black is dead lost in this game after move 24. Look at those pawns! And his King is in the middle of the board! However, Black's lead in development makes things like tripled pawns irrelevant. His superior mobility coupled with White's total lack of development carries the day.  As the Russians teach... a weakness is not a weakness if it cannot be exploited.

Comment: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12327/begginer-chess-question-bringing-out-my-queen-early

Comment: it's nice to see that bringing out the queen early and lack of development was punished.

Comment: This is a fine win between evenly matched players. However, your game is not without blunders; it is _without blunders for which you were punished_.  It looks like your issues wasn't that you played bad moves as such but failed to capitalize on your opponent's bad moves.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I'm actually the one who posted that :3

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, after 7.Qxb7??, the reply ...Bc6! simply traps the queen, leaving White completely busted. This may be the most obvious thing both players failed to notice in this game, and one of the few concrete ones I will bring up in this answer.

To me, it looks like this game is not an elite game, and it would be interesting to know your overall strength. I can assure you(without even analysing deeply), that black made more "mistakes" in this game than just missing 7...Bc6, but they may be more or less relevant depending on your level of self critisism, and ambition.

Let's take for example the position after 10.Qa6 by White: Did you consider playing ...Nb4, threatening both the queen on a6 AND a nice fork on c2? To me, not considering the move could be considered as a mistake, but at that point you already had quite a nice position, so most reasonable moves by black should be enough to win by then.

But there are other considerations to be made in the game. I think, that in this game, you did not develop your f8 bishop efficiently. This I view as a mistake, but it's not a tactical mistake, rather a positional one. But White never capitalised on this in any way, so you weren't punished for it. And this is the important point I wanted to make with this answer:

In this game, you outplayed your opponent, and the reason for it was that your opponent didn't play well enough to stop you from bullying his queen around the board. Therefore, your opponent will have a much easier time to learn from this game than you will. Your opponent got the "You play badly, and here's why"-treatment from you this game, but you didn't get the same treatment from anybody! Therefore you think you played great, no matter what the reality of your play is like.

This is the reason why it's easier to learn from your losses than from your victories in general. I would advise you to go through this game yourself with a bit more self-critisism, if you really want to take anything from it.

Comment: I'm not encouraging myself as GOOD really, but i was happy that I seem to have no blunders in this game.

Comment: Thinking that you made no blunders in this game will hold you back as a player. Tony Ennis' comment above explains it well; your opponent simply did not take advantage of the blunders that you did make.